# how do i reference these attributes without using the indexes of the data connection list?

Tags: python, class, attributes

load_file.py

```
class Connection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_type = None
        self.server = None
        self.port = None
        self.user = None
        self.password = None
        self.isActive = None
        self.file_extension = None
        self.file_contains = None
        self.file_location = None
        self.schedule_minutes = None
        self.interval_time = None
        self.last_ran = None

    def data_connection(self, data_connection_detail):
        self.connection_type = data_connection_detail[1]
        self.server = data_connection_detail[2]
        self.port = data_connection_detail[3]
        self.user = data_connection_detail[4]
        self.password = data_connection_detail[5]
        self.isActive = data_connection_detail[6]
        self.file_extension = data_connection_detail[7]
        self.file_contains = data_connection_detail[8]
        self.file_location = data_connection_detail[9]
        self.schedule_minutes = data_connection_detail[10]
        self.interval_time = data_connection_detail[11]
        self.last_ran = datetime.now()

    def get_connection(self):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT ID, Type, Server, Port, User, Password, isActive, FileExtension, FileContains, FileLocation, "
            "ScheduleMinutes, IntervalTime, LastRan from DataConnection WHERE isActive=True")

        return cursor.fetchall()
```

server_ftp.py

```
class EasyFTP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type_email = None
        self.isActive = None
        self.password = None
        self.user = None
        self.port = None
        self.server = None
        self.connection_type = None
        self.file_extension = None
        self.file_contains = None
        self.file_location = None

    def easy_ftp(self, data_connection_detail):

        # enter FTP server fields into datagrip once active
        self.type_email = data_connection_detail[1]
        self.server = data_connection_detail[2]
        self.port = data_connection_detail[3]
        self.user = data_connection_detail[4]
        self.password = data_connection_detail[5]
        self.isActive = data_connection_detail[6]
        self.file_extension = data_connection_detail[7]
        self.file_contains = data_connection_detail[8]
        self.file_location = data_connection_detail[9]

        # using hard coded config for FTP server fields for testing
        FTP_HOST = self.server
        FTP_USER = self.user
        FTP_PASS = self.password

        # connect to the FTP server
        with FTP(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS) as ftp:
            ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
            ftp.cwd('/files')
            for filename in ftp.nlst():
                # fnmatch compares single filename against a pattern '*' = matches everything
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, f'*{self.file_contains}*{self.file_extension}'):
                    with open(f'{self.file_location}/{filename}', 'wb') as fp:
                        ftp.retrbinary(f'RETR {filename}', fp.write)
```

what I am trying to do is not repeat using the 'data_connection_detail[1], [2], etc inside of the easy_ftp function as it is not a good practice. Instead I am trying to use the objects attributes from the function data_connection inside of the easy_ftp function.

If there is anything I could clarify further please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution; Not an answer and tangential to the question, but might something like this be a little bit tidier, and make future modifications much easier?

You've currently got the following code

```
    def data_connection(self, data_connection_detail):
        self.connection_type = data_connection_detail[1]
        self.server = data_connection_detail[2]
        self.port = data_connection_detail[3]
        self.user = data_connection_detail[4]
        self.password = data_connection_detail[5]
        self.isActive = data_connection_detail[6]
        self.file_extension = data_connection_detail[7]
        self.file_contains = data_connection_detail[8]
        self.file_location = data_connection_detail[9]
        self.schedule_minutes = data_connection_detail[10]
        self.interval_time = data_connection_detail[11]
        self.last_ran = datetime.now()
```

This could be simplified into the much shorter

```
def data_connection(self,data_connection_detail):
    connection_type,server,port,user,password,isActive,file_extension,file_contains,file_location,schedule_minutes,interval_time,last_ran=*data_connection_detail[1:],datetime.now()
    self.__dict__.update(locals())
```

Alternatively, maybe it's easier to pass `data_connection_detail` as a dictionary? Then you could just do

```py
def data_connection(self, data_connection):
    self.__dict__.update(data_connection|{'last_ran':datetime.now()})
```

Comment: I like your thinking but I am trying to eliminate the use of those indexes as a whole, The only place I want to list them are inside of data_connection and then I want to reference then as their var names inside of easy_ftp

Comment: You could have a list of the column names and use a dictionary comprehension to generate the dictionary.

Comment: could you give me an example of what you mean? A list of column names as a dictionary inside of data_connection? and generate them to easy_ftp?

Answer (score 0):

a better practice would be to inherit the Connection class inside the EasyFTP class and calling the init of the parent class (in this case Connection) then the easyftp class will automatically have all attributes already set

example EasyFTP:

```
import Connection
class EasyFTP(Connection):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.server)
```

Comment: I will look into some tutorials using super as I am not familiar with it. If you have the time to write out the example calling out the attributes from data connection that would be helpful